# Ensuring thread safety for cache fetching values on its own

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, rx-java

I built a generic cache that fetches values on miss by delegating to a `ValueGenerator` component. Internally, it has a map for values it has already obtained, and another map for in-flight requests so that they can be re-used across subscribers.

Here's the simplified code before I attempt to make it thread safe. My questions will follow.

```
public class NetworkCache<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> mValues;
    private final Map<K, Observable<V>> mRequests;

    private final ValueGenerator<K, V> mValueGenerator;

    public NetworkCache(ValueGenerator<K, V> valueGenerator) {
        mValues = new HashMap<>();
        mRequests = new HashMap<>();
        mValueGenerator = valueGenerator;
    }

    public Observable<V> get(final K key) {
        V value = mValues.get(key);

        if (value != null) {
            // We already had the value
            return Observable.just(value);
        }

        Observable<V> requestObservable = mRequests.get(key);

        if (requestObservable == null) {
            // New request to fetch the value
            requestObservable = mValueGenerator.generate(key);

            // Store in-flight request for potential re-use
            mRequests.put(key, requestObservable);

            requestObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<V>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() { mRequests.remove(key); }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) { mRequests.remove(key); }

                @Override
                public void onNext(V value) { mValues.put(key, value); }
            });
        }

        return requestObservable;
    }

    public interface ValueGenerator<K, V> {
        Observable<V> generate(K key);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to think how this could break under concurrency scenarios. I believe the focus should be on those two `Map` that are queried in `get()`, and modified in the `subscribe` callback.

I think it's reasonable to assume/enforce that this class can only be called on the main thread. The `ValueGenerator`, however, should be able to schedule its work on a different thread, as my use case is actually network requests.

I see 3 options, and I'd like help to figure out which one to use.

#### 1. Use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap`

Constructor would change to:

```
    public NetworkCache(ValueGenerator<K, V> valueGenerator) {
        mValues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        mRequests = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        mValueGenerator = valueGenerator;
    }
```

With this approach, I don't know if it is sufficient and/or overkill.

#### 2. Observe `ValueGenerator` call on main thread

To me, this means that all map operations would happen on the main thread (assuming that `NetworkCache` is only used there), even if the `ValueGenerator` used `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. This would mean it is thread safe.

```
if (requestObservable == null) {
    // New request to fetch the value
    requestObservable = mValueGenerator
        .generate(key)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
...
```

#### 3. Synchronize every access to the maps

I would keep using `HashMap` and the `get` method would become the following. Here, is synchronizing on the maps themselves the right approach? Do I need to block on every operation, or just `put` & `remove`?

```
public Observable<V> get(final K key) {
    V value;

    synchronized (mValues) {
        value = mValues.get(key);
    }

    if (value != null) {
        return Observable.just(value);
    }

    Observable<V> requestObservable;

    synchronized (mRequests) {
        requestObservable = mRequests.get(key);
    }

    if (requestObservable == null) {
        requestObservable = mValueGenerator.generate(key);

        synchronized (mRequests) {
            mRequests.put(key, requestObservable);
        }

        requestObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<V>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                synchronized (mRequests) {
                    mRequests.remove(key);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                synchronized (mRequests) {
                    mRequests.remove(key);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(V value) {
                synchronized (mValues) {
                    mValues.put(key, value);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return requestObservable;
}
```

A little background on the utilization: the cache's `get` method would be called in rapid succession 1-10 times for different keys. That event would be infrequent, but could happen within a few seconds. It's when the second series of calls arrives, mixed with the observables from the first series coming back, that I worry about the execution.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a single `ConcurrentMap` and `AsyncSubject`:

```
public class RequestCache<K, V> {
    final ConcurrentMap<K, AsyncSubject<V>> values;
    final Function<? super K, ? extends Observable<? extends V>> valueGenerator;

    public RequestCache(
            Function<? super K, ? extends Observable<? extends V>> valueGenerator) {
        this.values = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        this.valueGenerator = valueGenerator;
    }

    public Observable<V> get(K key) {
        AsyncSubject<V> result = values.get(key);
        if (result == null) {
            result = AsyncSubject.create();

            AsyncSubject<V> current = values.putIfAbsent(key, result);
            if (current == null) {
                Observable<? extends V> source = valueGenerator.apply(key);

                source.subscribe(result);
            } else {
                result = current;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is fully threadsafe and calls `valueGenerator` once per key only.

Comment: 1) Is it necessary to use a `ConcurrentMap` if I enforce that this cache can only be queried from a single thread (ex.: main)? 

2) Code is indeed simpler by having a single map. What's the advantage of storing `AsyncSubject` objects over `Observable`s on which we'd call `.cache()` before `putIfAbsent(key, result)`?

Comment: 1) If the cache is updated concurrently, then you need a ConcurrentMap or synchronize access. If you can make sure there is only one thread which queries the cache and the valueGenerator returns only synchronous Observables then you can get away with a Map.

Comment: 2) AsyncSubject stores only the very last value only; I assumed you only need one value per Observable. The advantage is functional: you can have an AsyncSubject before it is even decided that you need an Observable and won't work the other way as you'd have to call the generator then cache and finally check if not already started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should synchronize whole getter and setter functions.